# Error - Open clipboard failed

Tags: clipboard, visio

I am using Visio professional 2003. It was working fine. But now when I copy and paste any shapes it showing the error "Open clipboard failed". After that I am not able to change any properties or name.

When I try to close the window it is showing warning as "You cant quit visio program because a program is handling an event from visio. If VBA at break point, reset VBA, then quit"

Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Some other app is trying to control your clipboard, or you had something huge in there and it felt it didnt respond in time. Try closing down all unnecessary apps, and trying again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

this has been a problem with Visio for 7 years and the last 3 versions of the product([Visio 2003](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/42/214420.aspx) to [Visio 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/visiogeneral/thread/5f3b6b7b-e206-4c9e-b54a-cf430a7cc7ac)).

The issue happens if you are running some other clipboard manager, like [ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) or [similar](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-clipboard-replacement-utility.htm#Quick_Selection_Guide).  The only thing you can do is use task manager to kill visio, then disable any clipboard manager you are using and restart visio.

Comment: thanks for the hint, i was using Ditto and had the this problem. Disconnecting ditto from clip board fixes the issue for me.

Comment: @techventure yeah I discovered the 'disconnect from clipboard' option in ditto recently and this also fixed my issue.  Thanks for adding it to the answer, I'd forgotten about this :)

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine after i restarted the system.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to ring in that I had this issue when a Citrix session remoting to server 1 which was remoting to server 2 went into "triple lock": The screen saver in all three servers had kicked in. Ditto went crazy as did every app that I used the clipboard in.

Once I unlocked the sessions (which were lagging like crazy) everything went back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

On my side the issue was coming from Citrix. Thx for pointing that out Vincent.